# PHP using DOM to extract img src, and keep its place within text

Tags: php, regex, string

So I'm building a simple HTML **scraper**, in the text there are some images for the symbols and what I need is to get the src of this img tags, but keep them in the same place as the img tags where in the text.

--question rewritten due to me being asking the wrong thing.

Comment: If you're writing an HTML scraper, why aren't you using an HTML DOM parser instead of regexp?

Comment: HTML can't be parsed well with regExp, use HTML parser (read http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1529630)

Comment: Please don't use anything beyond an html traversal library to parse html, this community hates that more than anything.

Comment: I'm using everythin with HTML DOM, but this part was giving me trouble because I need to know where in the text each image is, and I failed to do it with DOM

Comment: If you already use a DOM parser, it should be able to extract the src attribute only. Perhaps if you asked about *that* instead, it might solve the *actual* problem faster.

Comment: Well sry for writing the question in the wrong way, but if I extract the src attribute, how do I get it to show in correct part of the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using DOM parser so you can extract image's src attribute in a variable. After that use following code:

```
$imgsrc = '/Handlers/Image.ashx?size=small&amp;name=3&amp;type=symbol';
$url = parse_url($imgsrc);
$query = htmlspecialchars_decode($url['query']);
parse_str($query, $arr);
echo $arr['name'] . "\n"; // prints 3
```

Comment: ok I get this, but how can I make sure it displayed at the same place where the original image was?

Comment: You can replace the image tag completely using [`DOMNode::replaceChild`](http://at.php.net/manual/en/domnode.replacechild.php)

Comment: I'm going to be out for a couple hours, will test it when I get back, ty so much.

Comment: That was a lot harder than I though it would be, but I managed to get it working, ty again.

Comment: You're welcome, glad that you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'd really suggest using a proper HTML parsing library to do this, but if it's really simple you can get away with a regex like `/<img[^>]*alt="(\d+?)"/` or so.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the `name=` part from the src attribute which is `/Handlers/Image.ashx?size=small&amp;name=3&amp;type=symbol` you can try this

```
<?php
$src = '/Handlers/Image.ashx?size=small&amp;name=3&amp;type=symbol';
$x = preg_replace('/^.*name=([^&]*).*$/i','[$1]',$src);
echo $x;
?>
```